Working with ASP.NET Core 6 and mysql server, is there a way to know the status of a stored procedure?
Currently I'm working on ASP.NET Core 6 and with a Mysql server. I'm working on functionality where frontend calls to us to, then, call a stored procedure which should disable this functionality (aka only be able to call it when the stored procedure is not running), is there a way to know if the stored procedure is running or not?
I've searched for information but I haven't come to anything useful/clear yet

You should be able to query this directly in the database see link

One idea is to create a status table where, when the SP starts, it should update a record with a status of 1, for example, and when the procedure finishes, it updates the status to 0. By reading the record from this table, you can determine whether the SP is running or not.
